# Comma inside like query fails to return any result

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle db,

```
Select name from name_table where name like 'abc%';
```

returns one row with value "abc, cd" but when I do a select query with a comma before % in my like query, it fails to return any value.

```
Select name from name_table where name like 'abc,%';
```

returns no row. How can I handle a comma before % in the like query?

Example:
Database has "Sam, Smith" in the name column when the like has "Sam%" it returns one row, when i do "Sam,%" it doesn't return any row

Comment: which db you  are using ..?

Comment: You need to separate out your name variables. LIKE 'abc1' OR LIKE 'abc2'

Comment: Database has "Sam, Smith" in the name column when the like has "Sam%" it returns one row, when i do "Sam,%" it doesn't return any row

Comment: Can you do `select dump(name, 16) from name_table where name like 'abc%';` and add the result to the question? I suspect it's not a normal comma, but maybe some other Unicode character that looks similar...

Comment: Could be the encoding on the comma. If you have a ms comma stored (say you or someone cut-n-pasted from MS Office) it won't match unless you use the same character.

Comment: encoding, you gotta love it.

Comment: Here is the dump result: Typ=1 Len=10: 47,4f,4f,47,4c,45,20,49,4e,43

Comment: That looks like the hex character codes for "GOOGLE INC".

Comment: That dump is of the string `'GOOGLE INC'`, which doesn't have a comma. I understand you might not want to provide real data but we can't help you if you don't give us anything we can use. Look at the dump yourself, and see which codepoint is reported for what you think is a comma, at least.

Comment: Yep.. The real data has different comma which is copied from ms word. Thanks  you

Answer (score 2):

**NOT AN ANSWER**  but posting it as one since I can't format in a comment.

Look at this and use DUMP() on your own machine... see if this helps.

SQL> select dump('Smith, Stan') from dual;

```
DUMP('SMITH,STAN')
-----------------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=11: 83,109,105,116,104,44,32,83,116,97,110
```

If you count, the string is 11 characters (including the comma and the space). The comma is character 44, and the space is character 32. If you look at YOUR string and you don't see 44 where the comma should be, you will know that's the problem. You could then let us know what you see there (just for that character, I understand posting "Leno, Jay" would be a violation of privacy).

Also, make sure you don't have any extra characters (perhaps non-printable ones!) right before the comma. Just compare the two strings you are using as inputs and see where the differences may be.

Comment: I think this is a decent [partial answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144452/is-it-okay-to-put-partial-answers), is about as complete as it can be with the information provided, and guides the OP in a reasonably helpful direction.